# How to update values in a nested json file by Powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I want to update some values of below content which i believe a  json file. This is the output of azure devops release definition and I need to reuse the content modifying some fields.

I can simply update values like id and name using these lines

$ReleaseDef.Name = $newReleaseName

$ReleaseDef.path = $folderQA

But I dont know how to update array fields like artifact and triggers. I can get values by calling $ReleaseDef.artifacts.sourceid

but can not set any values there , It throws errors like The property 'sourceid' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
property exists and can be set.

Please suggest

```
source            : userInterface

revision          : 4

description       : 

createdBy         : @{displayName=Jyotiprakash Nayak; url=https://azuredevopsdv
                    .ril.com/EntApps/_apis/Identities/2ca8bd5d-7797-4177-b7bb-2
                    6daa0d29ed9; _links=; 
                    id=2ca8bd5d-7797-4177-b7bb-26daa0d29ed9; 
                    uniqueName=domain\Jyotiprakash.Nayak; imageUrl=https://azuredev
                    opsdv.company.com/EntApps/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/win.
                    Uy0xLTUtMjEtMjIwNzU5NTE2Ni03MjEyNTY2NjUtNTU2MTkwNDkyLTQ4NjY
                    yMw; descriptor=win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtMjIwNzU5NTE2Ni03MjEyNTY2NjU
                    tNTU2MTkwNDkyLTQ4NjYyMw}

createdOn         : 2019-12-10T09:11:11.057Z

modifiedBy        : @{displayName=Jyotiprakash Nayak; url=https://azuredevopsdv
                    .company.com/EntApps/_apis/Identities/2ca8bd5d-7797-4177-b7bb-2
                    6daa0d29ed9; _links=; 
                    id=2ca8bd5d-7797-4177-b7bb-26daa0d29ed9; 
                    uniqueName=Domain\Jyotiprakash.Nayak; imageUrl=https://azuredev
                    opsdv.comapny.com/EntApps/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/win.
                    Uy0xLTUtMjEtMjIwNzU5NTE2Ni03MjEyNTY2NjUtNTU2MTkwNDkyLTQ4NjY
                    yMw; descriptor=win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtMjIwNzU5NTE2Ni03MjEyNTY2NjU
                    tNTU2MTkwNDkyLTQ4NjYyMw}

modifiedOn        : 2019-12-13T09:16:13.463Z
isDeleted         : False
variables         : 
variableGroups    : {}

environments      : {@{id=7; name=Stage 1; rank=1; owner=; variables=; 
                    variableGroups=System.Object[]; preDeployApprovals=; 
                    deployStep=; postDeployApprovals=; 
                    deployPhases=System.Object[]; environmentOptions=; 
                    demands=System.Object[]; conditions=System.Object[]; 
                    executionPolicy=; schedules=System.Object[]; 
                    currentRelease=; retentionPolicy=; processParameters=; 
                    properties=; preDeploymentGates=; postDeploymentGates=; 
                    environmentTriggers=System.Object[]; badgeUrl=https://azure
                    devopsdv.comapny.com/EntApps/_apis/public/Release/badge/e0b1a36
                    0-01a5-4eea-af57-b2a461559ac9/7/7}}

artifacts         : {@{sourceId=e0b1a360-01a5-4eea-af57-b2a461559ac9:48; 
                    type=Build; alias=_eCAM-Team-CI; definitionReference=; 
                    isPrimary=True; isRetained=False}}

triggers          : {@{artifactAlias=_eCAM-Team-CI; 
                    triggerConditions=System.Object[]; 
                    triggerType=artifactSource}}

releaseNameFormat : Release-$(rev:r)

tags              : {}
pipelineProcess   : @{type=designer}
properties        : @{DefinitionCreationSource=}
id                : 7
name              : Release-Template-1
path              : \QA
projectReference  :



url               : https://azuredevopsdv.company.com/EntApps/e0b1a360-01a5-4eea-af
                    57-b2a461559ac9/_apis/Release/definitions/7
_links            : @{self=; web=}
```

Comment: What do you get with `$ReleaseDef.artifacts` ?

Comment: I get the whole array sourceId            : e0b1a360-01a5-4eea-af57-b2a461559ac9:48
type                : Build
alias               : _eCAM-Team-CI
definitionReference : @{artifactSourceDefinitionUrl=; defaultVersionBranch=; defaultVersionSpecific=; defaultVersionTags=; defaultVersionType=; definition=; definitions=; 
                      IsMultiDefinitionType=; project=; repository=}
isPrimary           : True
isRetained          : False

Comment: Please provide the original Json string in your question rather than a formatted list of the converted object...

Comment: IRon, This is what I get from invoke-restmethod method get , and I need to make some changes and run post method.

Answer (score 0):

These attributes contain [hash table values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6).

You should be able to update by specifying the key and its new value like so:

`$ReleaseDef.artifacts["sourceid"] = "someValueHere"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion infosecb, but I ended up getting this error $ReleaseDef.artifacts["sourceid"] = "$($projectid):$($BuildID)"
Cannot convert value "sourceid" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."'''
At line:1 char:61
+ ... $ReleaseDef.artifacts["sourceid"] = "$($projectid):$($BuildID)"
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Comment: Although `ConvertTo-Json` accepts hash tables by default, `ConvertFrom-Json` ***Doesn't*** return **hash tables** but **pscustomobjects** (unless you provide the [`-AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6#parameters) parameter). To get a good understanding of the actual object, try this: `$Json | ConvertFrom-Json |` [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression)

Comment: @infosecb , Thanks for the hashtable idea, I tried like below ,but the json reads the artifact part as system.hastable

Comment: '''$hash =  [pscustomobject] @{
 sourceId=" sourceid";type=type";definitionReference = @{artifactSourceDefinitionUrl=  @{id = "id" ;name = ""} definition = @{id = "$BuildID";name = "$newReleaseName"} }; isPrimary = "True" ; "}}
  $hash | ConvertTo-Json '''

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable helps, I finally made it work through some foreach loops.

````
   ```$artifact =  $json.artifacts
      foreach ($value in $artifact)
      {
      $value.alias = "_$newReleaseName"
      $value.sourceId = "$($projectid):$($BuildID)"
      }
      foreach ($triggervalue in $snapshot.triggers)
      {
      $triggervalue.artifactAlias = "_$newReleaseName"
      }```
````